# Should BreezeJS share an Entity Manager across pages in a Single Page Application using Durandal?

Tags: breeze, single-page-application, durandal

What is the best practice for creating instances of the BreezeJS EntityManager for a Single Page Application using Durandal?

Should there be one instance of the Entity Manager that is shared across all pages, or should there be one instance for each page?

Any specifics on the implementation are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's up to what you want to accomplish. If you have 1 EntityManager (EM) shared then all data is shared in one place. Any changes are shared across views and viewmodels. When you press save, you save all screens. Usually in this case you want to prevent leaving a screen til the user saves or cancels.

If you want to be able to open different screens and save the data independently of each other, you could create multiple EMs. Then you can cancel one or save the other, however you want.

Or you could have an EM for areas of your app (probably more common). Really depends on what you want to do. If you don;t have a requirement to keep transactions separate, then 1 EM will suffice.